# vue.js - Send another field of selected object

Tags: json, vue.js

I have an autocomplete input form in vue. When the user selects a language from the suggestions, it shows the language's english name in the input field.

What I want to do is to send the iso_639_1 code of the language when user submits the form.

Language array:

```
{
    "iso_639_1": "tr",
    "english_name": "Turkish",
    "name": "Türkçe"
},
{
    "iso_639_1": "en",
    "english_name": "English",
    "name": "English"
},
...
```

Since english_name is the value of input, I can only send it. How can I submit the language's iso code while showing the english name to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3buxrm5y/2/

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="(locale, index) in locales" :key="index" :value="locale.iso_639_1">{{ locale.english_name }}</option>
</select>
</div>

<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        selected: null,
        locales: [{
            "iso_639_1": "tr",
            "english_name": "Turkish",
            "name": "Türkçe"
          },
          {
            "iso_639_1": "en",
            "english_name": "English",
            "name": "English"
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  })

</script>
```

As you can see you bind the select / autocomplete to the selected property and dislay the english_name whereas you bind the value to the iso.